# Best way to illustrate comments hyperlink on dropdown dashboard component?

Tags: interface, user-centered-design, hyperlinks, dashboard, comments

I'm designing a dashboard with dropdown components. Every component is a "driver" group. The dropdown consists of questions within the survey that belongs to this driver. Every driver consists of the:

1. Question
2. Benchmark
3. Benchmark decrease/increase within a month in comparison to the industry ie. 0.2 above Professional Service benchmark
4. Amount of user comments/ feedback within the driver survey. The user is able to click the comments- it's a hyperlink to the analysis page where he can preview the details of the comments.

I wonder how to design a comment hyperlink on a driver component...Do you think the message icon with amounts of comments next to it with underline is clear enough? Does someone have some better suggestions?  Below is a technical lo-fi overview of an exemplary element - it's content before wireframing.

Thank's for help.

[[image: technical lo-fi overview of an element:1]